# Google Fetch issue

Tags: google, google-search-console

When I do a Google fetch on any of my webpages the results are all the same (below).

I'm not a programmer but I'm pretty sure this is not correct. Out of all the fetches I have done only one was different and the content length was 6x below and showed meta tags etc.

Maybe this explains other issues I've been having with the site: a drop in indexed pages. Meta tag analyzer says I have no title tag, meta tags or description even though I do it on all pages.

I had an SEO team working on the site and they were stumped by why pages were not getting indexed. So they figure it was some type of code error. Are they right?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 11:45:41 GMT
Content-Length: 1054

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function getCookie(cookieName) {
            if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
                cookieStart = document.cookie.indexOf(cookieName + "=");
                if (cookieStart != -1) {
                    cookieStart = cookieStart + cookieName.length + 1;
                    cookieEnd = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cookieStart);
                    if (cookieEnd == -1)
                        cookieEnd = document.cookie.length;
                    return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cookieStart, cookieEnd));
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        function setTimezone() {
            var rightNow = new Date();
            var jan1 = new Date(rightNow.getFullYear(), 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);  // jan 1st
            var june1 = new Date(rightNow.getFullYear(), 6, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0); // june 1st
            var temp = jan1.toGMTString();
            var jan2 = new Date(temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" ") - 1));
            temp = june1.toGMTString();
            var june2 = new Date(temp.substring(0, temp.lastIndexOf(" ") - 1));
            var std_time_offset = (jan1 - jan2) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            var daylight_time_offset = (june1 - june2) / (1000 * 60 * 60);
            var dst;
            if (std_time_offset == daylight_time_offset) {
                dst = "0"; // daylight savings time is NOT observed
            } else {
                // positive is southern, negative is northern hemisphere
                var hemisphere = std_time_offset - daylight_time_offset;
                if (hemisphere >= 0)
                    std_time_offset = daylight_time_offset;
                dst = "1"; // daylight savings time is observed
            }

            var exdate = new Date();
            var expiredays = 1;
            exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
            document.cookie = "TimeZoneOffset=" + std_time_offset + ";";
            document.cookie = "Dst=" + dst + ";expires=" + exdate.toUTCString();
        }

        function checkCookie() {
            var timeOffset = getCookie("TimeZoneOffset");
            var dst = getCookie("Dst");

            if (!timeOffset || !dst) {
                setTimezone();
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="checkCookie()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is this code? This isn't very clear on what your are asking for ..

Comment: I guess this is showing what googlebot was able to fetch from my webpage which isn't much. The first time I did a fetch, it showed the html code for that page which included title tags, meta tags, decription etc.

Comment: This code is showing what googlebot was able to fetch or see from this webpage which isn't much. The first time I did a fetch, it showed the complete html code for that page which included title tags, meta tags, description etc. Now when I perform a google fetch it only can see this small bit of code for this page and all others on my site.

Comment: Is this part a of your code or nothing completely different?

Comment: What is your site? Are you using some kind of framework/CMS? Is your site dependent on knowing the clients timezone?

Answer (score 1):

1. [Meta tags do not affect your rankings](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html)
2. See that content between the `<body>` tags? That's what Google sees: *no content*. I don't know why this is happening but obviously something is very wrong somewhere in your site.